# FFMPEG Fade In Watermark Only

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to watermark a video using FFMPEG and would like the watermark to fade in.

The following code adds the watermark however the fade in effect is applied to the entire video and not just the watermark.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 3 -i background.png -i silence.mp3 -shortest -s 640x360 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in] [watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2,fade=in:0:30 [out]" -y output.mpg
```

I've searched online but have been unable to find a good example on how to apply the fade in only to the overlay.

Comment: Can you try setting the `fade=in:0:30` directly after `movie=watermark.png` instead?

Comment: @slhck, I tried `-vf "movie=watermark.png,fade=in:0:30 [watermark]; [in] [watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2 [out]` but unfortunately the watermark does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is not wrong, but not recommended.

Try using this:

`ffmpeg -y -pix_fmt rgb32 -f rawvideo -s 640x360 -i /dev/zero -vf 'movie=watermark.png[watermark];[in][watermark]overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2,fade=in:0:30[out]' -r 30 -t 3 output.mpg`

I will explain:

- Start from an empty source: `-pix_fmt rgb32 -f rawvideo -s 640x360 -i /dev/zero`
- load the watermark filter: `'movie=watermark.png[watermark];[in][watermark]overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h/2-overlay_h/2,fade=in:0:30[out]`
- set the frame rate: `-r 30`
- set the duration (in seconds): `-t 3`
- output to file (and format): `output.mpg`

I hope that helps.
E

Comment: Thanks E.G. for your answer, works great creating a black background. Is there anyway to have the watermark fade in with a white background?